# Client side Excel interop using Silverlight 4

Tags: c#, excel, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to see if it is possible to read an Excel spreadsheet on the client using Silverlight 4 and use Excel interop libraries to read the data.

I've seen sample code such as:

```
dynamic excel = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Excel.Application")
```

but how do I even know what is possible to do here if the dynamic keyword is used?

Answer (score 0):

Does Silverlight require that you work with dynamic objects? The Excel object model is documented here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms262200.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wss56bz7(VS.80).aspx